# Python3 write text file always get "invalid syntax" error

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

Got very strange syntax error in Python3 when I want to write a `.txt` file.
Also happened when I don't use `with open() as fz`.

```
with open('ff.txt','w') as fz:
    for m in range(17):
        for n in range(25):
            x = 425-m-n*17
            fz.writelines(str(x + ' '))
        fz.writelines('\n')
fz.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I receive this error
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

As @Scibor said the writelines must receive a list. But I think that the error you have is into concatenating a string with an array, in this line:

```
fz.writelines(str(x + ' '))
```

try like this:

```
with open('ff.txt','w') as fz:
    for m in range(17):
        for n in range(25):
            x = 425-m-n*17
            fz.writeline(str(x )+ ' ')
        fz.writeline('\n')
```

Comment: Ah, my answer was incomplete. Thank you for providing OP with the full solution!

Comment: @Miro If this worked for you, kindly accept it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

With the 'with' statement the 'close' method isn't required (exiting the block the file is automatically closed).

Comment: This is a valid critique of the code, but not the true cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

[writelines](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/file/writelines.html) takes a list as a parameter, not a string. Change this line:

```
fz.writelines(str(x + ' '))
```

to:

```
fz.writelines([str(x + ' ')])
```

and this line:

```
fz.writelines('\n')
```

to:

```
fz.writelines(['\n'])
```

Alternatively, just use `write` instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it will throw me this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'